# How do you access Running Devices in Android Studio Device Manager

Tags: android-studio

during Google io 2022 there was a session showing whats new in Android Studio.

one of the new features was the ability to see running devices in the embedded Device Manager.

the presenter was able to interact with the physical phone or via the running devices screen employing the pc mouse and/or keyboard.

i have installed dolphin and electric eel versions of Android Studio and cannot access the Running Devices window.

has this feature not been released yet?

or

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### With Android Studio `2022.2.1 | Android Studio Flamingo` or higher

If you don't see the `Running devices` tool window on the right-hand side:

- Go to `Settings > Tools > Device Mirroring`
- Check `Enable mirroring of physical Android devices`

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-flamingo-release-notes#device-mirroring)

#### If your version is lower

You need to manually enable the feature:

- In Android Studio, go to Preferences
- Click on the Experimental menu
- Enable Device mirroring at the bottom

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-electric-eel-release-notes#device-mirroring)

Comment: looks like the mirroring feature is only available in electric eel version.
Don't see any mirroring in experimental feature list for dolphin

Comment: From the official docu page: You can now mirror your device in the Running Devices window in Android Studio Electric Eel

Answer (score 12):

1. First of all, make sure you have Electric Eel edition of Android Studio.
2. Enable Mirroring:
   [image: screenshot of android studio showing screen mirroring]
3. Show Running Devices:
   [image: screenshot of android studio showing screen mirroring]

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio **Flamingo** option is in:

```
Settings -> Tools -> Device Mirroring
```

[image: Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

quick alternative to enable the mirror of physical device to android studio may be:
**make sure you have Electric Eel edition of Android Studio.**
Do global search for Experimental:
[image]